# When do you need to desolder a rectifier to check if its bad?

Tags: diodes, soldering, rectifier

So i have five high amp rectifiers on the board which i suspect are fried, because  when i test them with the multimeter, it shows that all of them are shorted. No matter on what legs i'm putting probes, in both directions, it shows shorting.

But i've read that sometimes you need to desolder them to check if they are bad, so maybe i'm measuring them wrong and that's why i'm getting shorts everywhere?
Do i need to desolder them to check them?

Pictures of schematics:

1 - Primary circuit:

[image: Primary]

2 - Secondary circuit:

[image: Secondary]

3 -Layout:

[image: Main Circuit]

I'm getting shorts on all 5 secondary rectifiers and 2 transformer outputs, shown with arrows.

Comment: Too many factors to give a definitive answer.  But the steps you have taken seem revealing assuming whatever meter you are using is giving you a conclusive short indication even when the probes are reversed.  Next I would look for inductors or transformer windings nearby which might be giving the low ohm reading.  At some point you are probably going to have to lift or snip at least one lead to measure the parts when they are disconnected. I would also consider the history of the failure and wonder if all 3 parts were likely to fail together.

Comment: Yeah there is a transformer there, and if i put probes on the transformer and rectifiers, they seem shorted too. Rectifiers seem to be in parallel, so i think the thing is here that if one blows, it will look like everyone is blown, because voltage will go through that blown rectifier when measuring. Could this be true?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the diode test function on your meter and they measure zero in both directions, at least one is probably shorted. To be sure lift one leg or cut a trace and test just the rectifier.

If you look at the schematic you may be able to see some sneak paths that would be present if a diode is shorted.. such as through a transformer secondary (which is very low resistance). Or maybe something else is FUBAR. Without a schematic it's just guessing.

Comment: Yeah, i actually just realized that they're in parallel(at least it looks like it), so that means that if one is shorted, they all will look shorted. And if i put probes on the secondary transformer from the diodes, they seem shorted there too. If i would post a schematic, could you help me read it?

Comment: Add it to the question at the bottom, indicating where you measure "shorts" and I or someone else will help you.

Comment: I updated my post with pictures of schematics, plus the layout of the board.